# Improperly Configured Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm  new to Django and Python. I try to create a project with the help of official tutorial on its website. Now I'm at the part 6 ("Customize your app’s look and feel") and I have a problem. When I run server (`python manage.py runserver`) everything is OK, I can even vote here http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/1/results/, but when I try to go at http://localhost:8000/polls/ I have such problem [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQJ8u.jpg)
. 
May someone explain how can I solve this problem? What should I check in my code?
I did everything the same as at the tutorial.
Any help would be very appreciated!

1)...\mysite\polls\views.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Choice, Question

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_qeryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions."""
        return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Excludes any questions that are not published yet.
        """
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())

class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'

def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExis):
        return render(request, 'polls/detai.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

2)...\mysite\polls\models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

def was_published_recently(self):
    now = timezone.now()
    return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

3)...\mysite\polls\urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

4)...\mysite\mysite\urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: Looks like you have a typo in your `IndexView` at `def get_qeryset(self)`. It should be `def get_queryset(self)`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks. I rewrote it correctly, but now, when I reload server I have another problem. "NoReverseMatch at /polls/1/results/
u'polls' is not a registered namespace" and I can't even vote. None of pages is available.

Comment: I added `app_name = 'polls'` to the ...mysite\polls\urls.py and everything works!

Comment: If you've solved your question you might consider posting that comment as an answer and accepting it yourself, that way people know the question has a solution and it's more visible for others experiencing the same problem.